# Secure Channel Protocol 80 and 81 description

Tags: javacard, ota, sim-card

I want to develop a toolkit applet for UICC. One of the aspects of this development is using SCP80,81 in OTA and handle it in UICC side but, I can't find the specification of SCP80,81 to implement the methods. Please let me know which standard describes this protocol in aspect of implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SCP80**

> ETSI TS 102 225 [Secured packet structure for UICC based applications;
> Release 9]
>
> ETSI TS 102 226 [Remote APDU structure for UICC based applications;
> Release 9]

**SCP81**

> GlobalPlatform Card Specification v.2.2 Amendment B: Remote
> Application Management over HTTP v1.1.1

Comment: Thank you. but it's not clear in these documents that which one is SCP80 or SCP81.

Comment: I just found the SCP81 in GlobalPlatform Card Specification Amendment B but I can't find the clear description about SCP80 in first and second document you mentioned

Comment: Packet structure for SCP80 is defined in ETSI TS 102 225. Based on structure, SPI coding is there. Please go through section 5 in this document.

Comment: Scp80 basically define whether packet are enciphered on not. Based on that that encryption you get from spi table. You will get to know how will you decrypt packets.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to find the place where this connection between specifications and numbers (80, 81) is defined.

Here is a quote from the [GlobalPlatform Card Specification v2.3.1](https://globalplatform.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GPC_CardSpecification_v2.3.1_PublicRelease_CC.pdf) section **10.7 Secure Channel Protocol Identifier**:

> The following values are assigned to the Secure Channel
> Protocol identifier:
>
> ...
>
> - '80' to 'EF' – Reserved for use by individual schemes registered by GlobalPlatform
>
>   - '80' – Secure Channel Protocol '80' defined in [TS 102 225] and [TS 102 226]
>   - '81' – Secure Channel Protocol '81' defined in [Amd B] based on HTTP and Pre-Shared Key TLS
>     protocols

[Amd B] is **GlobalPlatform Card Specification 2.2 Amendment B
v1.1.3 – RAM over HTTP** as defined section **1.3 References** of that specification.